# How to import a document class file and play it out on a frame

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, document

I have 2 flash files, one with an intro and the second that just has a document class file that plays out a snake game. How could i import that document flash file and make it play out on like frame 100 off my other flash file.

Thankyou for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate the Snake class file in your intro, using code like the following on frame 100:

```
var game:Snake = new Snake();
addChild(game);
```

assuming your document class is called `SnakeGame`. You may have to make a few changes in `SnakeGame` for this to work, however. The `stage` and `root` properties of `SnakeGame` will be null in the constructor when using this method. This is different behavior from it's was the document class (or placed directly on the stage) -- `stage` and `root` are already initialized. So if you do any actions to either `root` or `stage` in the constructor, you must change this or you will get an error. To fix this, listen for the `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event in `Snake`:

```
public function Snake() {
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
}

public function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    // stage+root are now valid, put your init code here
}
```

Alterantively, you could link the `Snake` class to an empty MovieClip symbol and place that directly on the stage on frame 100. First, create an empty MovieClip by going to Window->Library and clicking the +. In the Create New Symbol dialog, check "Export for ActionScript" and type in `Snake` in the Class field under Linkage. Now you can drag that MovieClip directly onto the stage on frame 100 and it hopefully will work without changes to the code.

Comment: so where should my Snake.as file be? in the same folder as the other fla file? im confused as to what you mean with the root and stage. i have added listeners to the stage in the class file. Would it help if i ammended my post with the class file in its entirety.

Comment: Your Snake.as file should be in the same folder as the intro.fla (assuming Snake is in the default package). Since you have added listeners to the stage in the class file, you will probably have to use the `ADDED_TO_STAGE` code and add the stage listeners in the onAddedToStage function.

Comment: Ahh i see, so for instance i have the public function Snake() and inside it i have stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,changeDir); would i have to put this in a seperate function and call it with the      ADDED_TO_STAGE code in the Snake() function?

Comment: Yep, you got it! The reason is that the stage is not set when Snake is first created, it only gets set when you actually add the child to the stage. So you have to wait for that event or you'll get an error.

Comment: ,ive linked it on frame 82. but im getting this error.  flash file is called lightcycleTron, i have a button on the first couple of pages that calls a function called saveNameAndGo which goes to frame182 (i have added the code var game:Snake = new Snake();
addChild(game);                                                 TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Snake()
 at lightcycleTRON_fla::MainTimeline/frame182()
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
 at lightcycleTRON_fla::MainTimeline/saveNameAndGo()

Comment: Looks like something in the Snake constructor is null when you try to access it (it's likely the stage/root issues I mentioned above.) You can hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter and hit the play button to run your movie in debug mode, and it should show you the exact line that is the problem.

Comment: hmmm im getting alot of errors in  snake.as file. the first being that im i have this in my snake function.  size = stage.stageWidth / DIM; //change grid size

Comment: if you want to look at my as file - http://www.ignitethatdesign.com/FlashLeaderBoard/Snake.as

Comment: You can't use stage in your constructor (the `Snake()` function) because stage doesn't exist at that point. You should do is cut all of the code in the constructor except for the `ADDED_TO_STAGE` listener and paste it into the `onAddedToStage` function.

Comment: I added an alternative solution to my answer above -- that method doesn't require change to the code.

Comment: that is perfect thankyou. however all of the animation that happens before 182 starts over again? any way of stopping that

Comment: Hi Mike, are you any good at hit detection? On the snake i want to test when it hits its tail? been messing about for hours on it with no avail :S